# How can we reset the repeatCount property while the timer is running

Tags: actionscript-3

How can we reset the repeatCount property while the timer is running.

In a game a countdown timer starts running at 120. If the user clicks on "hint" button i need to reduce the time by 5 seconds and start displaying the countdown

Now the problem is the countdown timer is reduced by five but the Timer runs till "-n*5".
"n" being the number of times hint button clicked.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please show a code example so we have better context.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach to your problem. Maintain a timer count separate from the Timer's `repeatCount`, and stop when that separate counter hits 0, instead of when the TimerComplete event occurs.

```
public var t:Timer;
public var count:int = 120;

protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
{   
    t = new Timer(1000,count);
    t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
    t.start();
}

protected function onTimer(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
    count--;
    //display count as time remaining

    if (count <= 0)
    {
        //out of time!
        t.stop();
    }
}

protected function onHint(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    count-=5;
    //update time or wait for next tick
}
```